# crystal report, tsql

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports

I am working on crystal report with backend as sql server 2005.
Report is used to display tenant details with a flat in which he is residing. On filter screen i have filter Sort By tenant or unit.

When I sort by tenant, details appear as shown below,

```
Tenant name   tenant_unit tenant_rent
A             160         1000
              180         1000
B             170         2000
```

When sort by Unit, details appear as shown below,

```
Tenant name   tenant unit tenant rent
A             160         1000
B             170         2000
A             180         1000
```

My question is, Is there any way to bring details in one line instead of two lines when sorting by unit?

FYI: On crystal I have group of tenant with sort order original.

Comment: It's difficult to understand the sorted output, please edit your question and format it.

Comment: Sorting should not change the number of rows returned, are you doing a record filter (under Report > Select Expert > Record) ?

Comment: hi bendataclear, just updated the example. Plase have a look at that. you will understand it more clearly. No record filter is used.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want now, if you want to display details for a single tenant on one row with totals, what you need is a group:

```
Tenant name   tenant_rent
A             2000
B             2000
```

To do this you can add a group on Tenant (Under Report > Group Expert) then right click on the tenant_rent field and go to Insert > Summary then set the location to 'Group 1'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have a group of tenant with sort order original. My query is sorting data by unit due to which i am getting two records for same tenant as they have units 160 and 180.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have a group of tenant with sort order original. Let me put it in other words; I need a custom sort which sorts by unit when tenant have single unit attached to it and sorts by tenant when tenant have two units attached to it.

Comment: You can add another level of sorting so it sorts by Tenant THEN by unit, this would mean for single tenants the first sort would be ignored.